# Azure Graph API : Authentication_MissingOrMalformed

Tags: azure, libcurl

I am getting the Authentication_MissingOrMalformed, getting the token properly and assigned in the header.

```
// Curl call for calling graph API
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.windows.net/xxxx/users/giri@xxxx.com/memberOf?api-version=1.6",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_PROXY => "xxxxx:8080",    
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "api-version=1.0",
  // Adding access toker here
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer ".$result->access_token,
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  ),
```

Comment: Could you inspect your access token at e.g. https://jwt.ms? Since you are calling Azure AD Graph API, the aud claim needs to match the URL for it :)

Comment: URL?               
 this URL https://graph.windows.net/{{tenent_id}}/users/giri@xxxx.com/memberOf?api-version=1.6                                                                                                                          when I decode "aud" value is right.

Comment: Yeah aud value should be `https://graph.windows.net`

Comment: Why are you specifying api version 1.0 in the postfields? You already specified the version in the query string

Comment: Oh!!! my aud value is different not https://graph.windows.net. removed the post field

Comment: Then you have acquired the token for a different API. Could you show the part where you do that?

Comment: curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenent_id}/oauth2/token",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={{client_is}}&resource={{my company resource id }}&client_secret={{client_secret}}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  ),
));

Comment: Replace my company resource id with `https://graph.windows.net` :) Or if you need to access both APIs then you'll need to acquire both.

Comment: Actullay "Aud" is showing resource details when I decode the token. should i need to give that instead of https://graph.windows.net?

Comment: Yes i replaced it No error but i am not getting my user details.

Comment: "error": { "code": "BadRequest", "message": "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format."

Comment: Remove your content type header?

Comment: Also, change it to a get if you want to get data

Comment: Do you have any update about this? If it is useful, you could mark it as answer to close it.

Comment: Now i am using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx@xx.com. getting this error "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."  I checked the configuration team they told gave all privileges. Not sure what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error information `Authentication_MissingOrMalformed` it means that the access resource is not match the aud of accesstoken.

As Juunas mentioned that you need to change the resource to `https://graph.windows.net` during get the accesstoken.

According to [GetUsersMemberships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsersMemberships) API, we could know that content-type should be application/json and the http method is `GET`.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

So you also need to change content-type from  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json`.